# many pip files, which is right?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip

I tried to type `pip install pipenv` in Visual Studio Code, then i got `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` So i was looking for some solution at the internet and there i found that i have to add path to windows enviroment variables. I found the pip file in location `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\` and there are `pip3.8`, `pip3`, `pip`, `pipenv` and any other files. Also i found in location `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\` files: `pip`, `pip3.7`, `pip3`(it is from older version of python i think). The current `PATH` in system enviroment variables is `C:\Users\Patrik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip3.8.exe`. I tried to reinstall python, add pip during installation and nothing helped me to fix it.

Any ideas guys?

I'm using Windows 8.1 and Python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use use `python -m pip install pipenv` this will use your current system python pip version to install pipenv and you don't need to worry about the version

Comment: Okay, then when i type pipenv shell i get 'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. What now?

Comment: use `python -m pipenv`

Comment: and when i want to create a virtual environment i typed `python3 -m venv my_kivy_project` and i get the same error

Comment: install virtualenv first `python -m pip install virtualenv` then use the above command

Comment: i got `C:\Windows\System32\hello>python -m pip install virtualenv`
`Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (16.7.9)`
then
`C:\Windows\System32\hello>python -m venv my_kivy_project`
`Error: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\hello'`

Comment: run the terminal as administrator then run all these command or change the working directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205838/discussion-between-author-climent-and-sahasrara62).

Comment: Don't create directories in C:\Windows\System32; that directory is for Windows own private use. Best to create a directory somewhere else like Documents or Desktop.